# "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error

Tags: matlab

I run a code and "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" appears as an error but I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
function [ p ] = myIsort2(p)
%myIsort2 is based on myIsort but instead of sorting a row vector into 
%increasing order it sorts a structure array into decreasing order

global order

n=length(p);

for i=2:n

    x=p(1,i).exponent;
    y=p(1,i).coeff;
    j=i-1;

    while (j~=0) && order(x,p(1,j).exponent)==1

        %compares the order between 2 row vectors of the exponential field 
        %in order to sort them by making the smallest one come after the
        %largest one

        p(1,j+1).exponent=p(1,j).exponent;
        p(1,j+1).coeff=p(1,j).coeff;
        j=j-1;

    end

    p(1,j+1).exponent=x;
    p(1,j+1).coeff=y;

end

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the error without having the input parameters and the line where the error occurs. At least I don't see any obvious error. I would try using `dbstop if error` and check the indices when it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be accessing `p`, which is accessed with indices going from `p(1,1)` to `p(1,n)` with `n = length(p)`.

If you are getting an `index exceeds matrix dimensions` error, the conclusion is that `p` has less than `n` columns. Note that [`length`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) is the size of the *largest* dimension of `p`. So if `p` has more rows than columns, this error will show up.

An example:

- Suppose `p` is `<10x5 double>`.
- `n = length(p)` returns `n = 10`.
- However, `p(1,10)` returns `Error: index exceeds matrix dimensions` because `p` has only 5 columns.

Instead of `length`, use [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) to get the sizes of all dimensions, or [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) to get the total number of elements.